# xsd2java tools?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Is there a tool for converting an xsd in java class?
I remember that I used one called xsd2java but I don't remember where it is.

Comment: I seem to remember it is Apache Ant tool....may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the XJC binding compiler

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/xjc.html

But it creates jaxb compliant java objects with annotations. So you would have to remove the jaxb stuff

Answer (score 4):

You can edit wsdl2java.bat OR wsdl2java.sh in axis installation folder and replace **org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java** with **org.apache.axis2.schema.XSD2Java**, better to saveAS wsdl2java.bat file to xsd2Java.bat

Answer (score 3):

Apache's XMLBeans: http://xmlbeans.apache.org/

Use scomp to generate Java classes from the desired schema.

Answer (score 1):

**Apache Axis has [xsd2java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/schema/XSD2Java.html).**

There is an [ANT task for wsdl2java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/ant/axis-wsdl2java.html), but I don't believe there is one for xsd2java.

**[xsd2java](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/schema/XSD2Java.html) does have a main() method where you can specify the source schema and output location.**

Answer (score 1):

see also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3269 - perhaps this RFE will eventually lead to the shell script. But you can really copy wsdl2java and replace the java class - it works